# Subtract each elements of an array consecutively

Tags: c++

I have an array and I want to subtract each of the elements consecutively, ex: {1,2,3,4,5}, and it will result to -13 which is by 1-2-3-4-5.

But I don't declare or make those numbers fixed as they're taken from the input (user). I only make it like, int array[100] to declare the size.

Then, to get the inputs, I use the for loop and insert them to the array. Let's say first input is 10, then array[0] must be 10 and so on.

The problem is, how do I subtract them? I have two options:

1. The first element of the array (array[0]) will subtract the next element (array[1]) right after the user input the second element, and the result (let's say it's int x) will subtract the next element (array[2]) after the user input it and so on.
2. I'll have the user input all the numbers first, then subtract them one by one automatically using a loop (or any idea?) *These elements thing refer to the numbers the user input.

Question: How do you solve this problem?

(This program will let the user input for as much as they want until they type **count**. Frankly speaking, yeah I know it's quite absurd to see one typing words in the middle of inputting numbers, but in this case, just how can you do it?)

Thanks.

Let's see my code below of how I insert the user input into the array.

```
string input[100];
int arrayInput[100];
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i >= 0; i++) //which this will run until the user input 'count'
{
   cout << "Number " << i+1 << ": ";
   cin >> input[i];
   arrayInput[i] = atoi(input[i].c_str());
   ...
   //code to subtract them, and final answer will be in int x
   ...
   if (input[i] == "count")
   {
      cout << "Result: " << x << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: `i = 0; i >= 0` the loop will be run only once. Is that what you expect it to do? If yes, you don't need the loop at all. BTW, please post what have you tried so far, currently it seems like you are asking to solve an assignment.

Comment: How would you _sum_ elements of the array? This problem is very similar

Comment: Well, I somehow posted it when it's still draft. Anyway, I've included the code. Any suggestion?

Comment: You don't need an array for this, as there appears to be no qualifier that says you must regurgitate it. You also don't need string to integer conversion either, as the standard overloads for `operator >>` will do that for you when presented with the proper arguments. All you need do is read the first integer, prime your initial value, then spend the rest of the program reading additional values (with a loop), one at a time, subtracting them from your running tally, then printing the final tally at the end.

Comment: @WhozCraig Can you make an example of it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can/should use a dynamic sized container like `std::vector` as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
   
    int n = 0;
    
    //ask user how many input he/she wants to give 
    std::cout << "How many elements do you want to enter: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    
      std::vector<int> vec(n); //create a vector of size n 
      
      int resultOfSubtraction = 0;
      //take input from user 
      for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
      {
          std::cin >> vec.at(i);
          
            if(i != 0)
            {
                resultOfSubtraction-= vec.at(i);
            }
            else 
            {
              resultOfSubtraction = vec.at(i);  
            }
      }
      std::cout<<"result is: "<<resultOfSubtraction<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Execute the program [here](https://onlinegdb.com/ducHX5KkA).

If you want a `string` to end the loop then you can use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    
    std::vector<int> vec;

    int resultOfSubtraction = 0, i = 0;
    std::string endLoopString = "count";
    
    std::string inputString;
    int number = 0;
      //take input from user 
    while((std::getline(std::cin, inputString)) && (inputString!=endLoopString))
    {
        std::istringstream ss(inputString);
        if(ss >> number)
        {
            vec.push_back(number);
            if(i == 0)
            {
                resultOfSubtraction = number;
            }
            else 
            {
                resultOfSubtraction-= number;
            }
            ++i;
        }
        
    }
   std::cout<<"result is: "<<resultOfSubtraction<<std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not what exactly how I want it to be, as I want to let the user input the numbers continuously until they input the word **count** to get the result.

Comment: @Riiko You're making your program much more rigid and complex and ugly by using things that aren't necessary. For example, you don't need the `input` array to check for loop break condition. Also, in your question you only said that you have an array and you want to subtract all of its elements without ever mentioning about the loop breaking condition.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I didn't write it there. Well, it's just to my convenient that I want the user to determine when to stop the loop without the need to specify it beforehand.

Comment: @Riiko Ok then have you decided how will the user end the loop. For example, lets say if he/she enters a particular string like "count" or a particular integer like -1 which will be used to decide to end the loop? My question is how will the user know beforehand to enter a particular thing to end the loop.

Comment: I didn't write my whole code here as I still have other functions and so on, so I just focus the matter on this one. Point is, there's an instruction that prompts the user to end the loop by inputting that string or a particular integer like what you've stated.

Comment: @Riiko Instead of prompting the user everytime whether to end the loop you can just ask at the beginning how many elements they want to enter.

Comment: Can it not be done in this way? Assuming the word count or whatever the trigger is as the 'equal to' thing.

Comment: @Riiko It can be done as i did [here](https://onlinegdb.com/mJEV1HLLk). In this link, when you run the program the user enters some numbers one by one. Lets say first he enters 1 and then press enter, second he enters 2 and press enter and then he enter 3 and press enter and then he enters 4 and press enter and then he enters 5 and press enter. **Lastly** he enters **count** and press enter and the loop breaks and the result of subtraction is shown on the screen. I have added the same example at the end of my answer check it out.